# Computing an expectation using symmetry and indicator functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

> Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random
>   variables with density $f$. Also, define
>
> $$\eta = \# \left\{k \leq n \mid X_{k} \geq \min_{i \leq n} X_{i} +
>  2\right\}.$$
>
> What is the value of $\mathbb{E}\eta$?

I am really not so sure how to solve this question. The notation I am using $\#\{\cdot\}$ is used to denote the cardinality of a set. I am given the following hint:

**Hint:** Write $\eta$ as the sum of indicator functions and use symmetry arguments.

Even with this hint, I am not sure how to solve the problem. I guess that we should define $I_{k}$ to be $1$ if $k \leq n$ and $X_{k} \geq \min_{i\leq n} X_{i} + 2$ so that we can write $\eta = \sum_{k=0}^{n} I_{k}$? Then I need $\mathbb{E}[I_{k}] = P(k \leq n \text{ and } X_{k} \geq \min_{i \leq n} X_{i} + 2)$.

I am not even sure if this is correct and even if it is I don't know how to proceed.

I will appreciate your assistance in solving this question. I guess (but not sure) that the answer should be in terms of the density $f$. Otherwise, there is no reason for the problem to introduce this notation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can simply define $I_k$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$. Then indeed, 
$\eta=\sum_{k=0}^nI_k$ and 
$$\mathbb E\left[I_k\right]=\mathbb P\left(X_k\geqslant \min_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i+2\right).$$
Observing that the vectors $\left(X_k,\min_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i\right)$ and  $\left(X_0,\min_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i\right)$ have the same distribution (this is were the symmetry comes into play), it suffices to compute $\mathbb E\left[I_0\right]=\mathbb P\left(X_0\geqslant \min_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i+2\right)$. To this aim, we first notice that 
$$
\left\{X_0\geqslant \min_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i+2\right\}=\left\{X_0\geqslant \min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i+2\right\}.
$$
The probability of the complement is maybe easier to compute: by Fubini's theorem, 
$$
\mathbb P\left\{X_0\lt \min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i+2\right\}=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\mathbb P\left\{x \lt \min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i+2\right\}dx.
$$
Then use independence to simplify this.

Comment: Hey, could you please clarify how I can use independence to simplify this quantity? I guess you mean that I can write $P(x < \min_{1\leq i \leq n X_{i} + 2}$ as $P(X_{1} + 2, X_{2} + 2, \ldots, X_{n} + 2 > x) = P(X_{1} + 2 > x)^{n}$. Is that right? If so, how do I simplify this?

Comment: This is indeed what I mean and also the simplification I meant. I don't know whether we can do better than this.

Comment: So I guess I can write it as $P(X_{1} + 2 > x)^{n} = (1 - F(x - 2))^{n}$, right? Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)(1 - F(x - 2))^{n}$

Comment: So for $E(\eta)$ would it just be $n \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) P(x < \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i + 2) \mathop{dx}$? (is it okay for me to just multiply by $n$?)